# Recovery of table

Tags: oracle

How to recover a deleted table on a production database, with and without using RMAN?

Comment: This may be more appropriate at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

What version of Oracle is this?  If it's 10G or above you can bring it back from the recyclebin.  For example,

```
Flashback table bla to before drop;
```

Alternately, if you simply deleted the data you can get the data back using Flashback Query.

Answer (score 2):

If you drop table you can find in recycle bin.

```
select object_name, original_name, type, can_undrop as "UND", can_purge as "PUR", droptime
from recyclebin;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dump/export of the data, you could re-import the table and data with the import (imp) or the Data Pump import (impdp) utility.  Information on importing and exporting can be found [here](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Oracle+export+and+import+).

If the deletion occurred relatively recently, you could use Flashback Query to recover the data.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO EMP_TMP
    (SELECT * FROM EMP AS OF TIMESTAMP ('14-FEB-11 10:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24: MI: SS');
```

Here is a nice [link](http://tonguc.wordpress.com/2007/01/01/oracle-10g-flashback-versions-query-drop-table-and-recyclebin-management/) about the feature.  The length of the availability of the data will depend on your UNDO_RETENTION parameter as it essentially uses the undo information to create the snapshot of the data as it existed at that point in time.